# Test - Does Azure AD supports ABAC (attribute based access control)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

Was wondering if AAD supports ABAC. Where can I find more information?

Comment: No. Azure supports RBAC. Vote this [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35926891-azure-active-directory-should-support-abac-cbac-ub) if you need ABAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move comment to answer so that this issue is treated as archived.

No. Azure supports RBAC. Vote this [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35926891-azure-active-directory-should-support-abac-cbac-ub) if you need ABAC.

Answer (score 1):

Azure ABAC features are currently in [preview status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-overview#where-can-conditions-be-added). Enforcement is currently limited to [blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-overview#where-can-conditions-be-added).